# @webpack-cli/init npm install failure [webpack-cli]

Tags: npm, webpack

I tried installing `webpack && webpack-cli` and the installation was successful, but i when i tried installing `@webpack-cli/init` i got this error message:

`npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...f7d7c27ab73cfaae06c46'`

[image]

I have searched if this error exits but could not find anything. Please what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Update your deprecated packages and see if the problem persists?

Answer (score 1):

Just clear npm cache
npm cache clean --force

that solved my problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It also solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

[image: Works for me.] Works for me. Try resetting cache or something.

Comment: Hello Dhruvdutt,

I resolved the issue, but this took a while though... Thanks for your help